Getting InvalidToken from Authorization in ASP.NET Core Web API
When I am trying to call API from ajax call with GET method, I am getting an invalid token. I have checked app setting and other keys those are fine.
Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(config =>
    {
        config.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        config.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(config =>
    {
        TokenOptions token = jwtOptions.TokenOptions;
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token.Key);

        config.SaveToken = true; //save the claims in Authentication property(Users)

        config.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            //ValidIssuer = jwtOptions.Issuer, //single issuer
            ValidIssuers = token.Issuers.Split(";").ToList(), // multiple issuer
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),

            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = token.Audience,

            ValidateLifetime = true // validate token expiry
        };

        config.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                            context.Response.Headers.Add("IS-TOKEN-EXPIRED", "True");

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                string authorization = context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];

                if (context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("X-Access-Token"))
                {
                    context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["X-Access-Token"];
                }
                else if(authorization.IsNullOrEmpty())
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("IS-COOKIE-EXPIRED", "True");
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(config =>
    {
        config.AddPolicy(***.AuthorizationPolicyName, configPolicy =>
        {
            configPolicy.AddRequirements(new ***Requirement(jwtOptions.TokenOptions.Issuers));
        });

        config.AddPolicy(***.VendorOnBoardingPolicy, config =>
        {
            string employee = Convert.ToString((short)UserRoles.Employee);

            config.RequireRole(employee)
                  .RequireClaim(claimType: ClaimTypes.GroupSid, EmployeeGroups.VO.ToString(), EmployeeGroups.VOM.ToString());
        });
    });

Controller:
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]  
  [Authorize(Policy = ***.AuthorizationPolicyName)]
  public class HomeController : ControllerBase
  {

Note: everything working fine on local but when I am deploying my MVC app and ASP.NET Core Web API on a different port on IIS it throwing "Invalid Token:Signature key was not found". When I removed ValidateKey, it starts throwing "Invalid Audience".
We have tried to remove Authorize tag from home controller .its working fine but we can not remove that on live.
Also we tried to remove signature key validation from token validation parameters but then we got Audience invalid issue.When We remove audience check then got issuer invalid issue.

It may be due to different environment variables used after deployment. You can check whether the configuration files in the production environment (such as appsettings.json) are consistent with the configuration files in the local environment.
